# How to reuse Azure DevOps pipeline template for different service connections?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Azure Devops pipeline I have created a template for a Docker build. In it there is this build command (nothing special):

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: build
    condition: <multiple implementations>
    containerRegistry: 'My-ContainerRegistry-Connection'
```

The template is quite complex and there are different `Docker@2` tasks for different purposes that are executed under different conditions.

Now I want to reuse this template in another project using another `containerRegistry`, but the same template. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-service-connection) and [this Answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/containerRegistry-as-varibale/1036752#T-N1037509) I cannot set the `containerRegistry` in a variable or parameter:

> Resources are authorized before a stage can start running, so stage- and job-level variables aren't available. Pipeline-level variables can be used, but only those explicitly included in the pipeline.

Is there any way I can define the `containerRegistry` dynamically per project or pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define a step to login to the container registry as parameter and execute it before the build step.

The `containerRegistry` parameter hat to be omitted, because the connection will the already be established.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: docker_login_steps
  type: stepList
  default:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to Azure Container Registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'My-ContainerRegistry-Connection'
        command: login

  # ...   

jobs:
- job:
  # Execute the 'docker_login_steps'
  - ${{ each step in parameters.custom_docker_login_task_steps }}:
    - ${{ step }}

  # build image
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      command: build
      condition: <multiple implementations>
      # do NOT add this: containerRegistry: 'My-ContainerRegistry-Connection'
```